# Document plug-in won't wrap text in Excel cells on the SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, excel-web-access-webpart, excel-access-web-part

I am displaying an Excel document on the SharePoint page and for some reason, the cell text is not wrapped and that causes the text to go over each other which looks really bad and unreadable.

But once it is opened either in Excel online or regular Excel, then it looks fine, the text is wrapped and everything looks good. I really have no idea why this is happening.

I am using the modern look SharePoint, here is a picture of what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I believe in Excel file there is a wrap button. see below image:

[image]